# How to determine inherited class in an array of type?

Tags: c#

Say I have these class:

```
Class Animal;

Class Tiger: Animal;
Class Bear: Animal;
Class Giraffe: Animal;
```

And this array:

```
Animal[] p = [new Tiger(), new Bear(), now Giraffe()]
```

How do I determine that:

```
(p[0] is Tiger)
```

I got a message that p[0] is always an animal, not a Tiger

Comment: it seems ok. Can you give some real code examples?

Comment: Correcting your own code for typos and running in Linqpad, I see that `(p[0] is Tiger)` returns `true`, and `p[0].GetType() == typeof(Tiger)` is also `true`.  What message did you get?  What are you actually doing in code?

Comment: You need to post your full code then - the above code isn't valid C# and you apparently have something wrong that we can't see :-)

Comment: I just discovered that I mistakenly typed (p is Tiger). Then I change it to (p[i] is Tiger) and everything seems fine. I apologize for posting this but I cannot delete this question since it is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed this ?

```
p[0].GetType() == typeof(Tiger)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) like:

```
var tigersInArray = p.OfType<Tiger>();
```

The above would return you `Tiger`(s) from the array.

Your check `(p[0] is Tiger)` should work, make sure you have Tiger at position `0` in the array.

Comment: That's not quite what the question asks: this answers "how do I find all elements of type `X`", not "how do I find what type element `n` is."

Comment: Dan, I had that in the answer but then removed it. I believe the OPs check is fine its just the array element that doesn't have Tiger at position `0`

Answer (score 1):

It's an Animal *and* a Tiger, because a Tiger is an Animal. As soon as you put the Tiger into the array, you lose the information about the specific type, but the object itself still knows.

You can still figure out its type and cast it back:

```
if (p[0] is Tiger)
    Tiger tiger = (Tiger)p[0];
```

or

```
Tiger tiger = p[0] as Tiger;
if (tiger != null)
    ...
```